# Trapped in iPhone 4 and WhatsApp, need help to escape

Tags: iphone, migration, whatsapp.app

I have an iPhone 4 with WhatsApp messenger installed. The iPhone doesn't update anymore, works deadly slow, and does not have any free space.  WhatsApp also does not update anymore, because newer WhatsApp versions require newer version of iOS, which in turn will require me to get a new iPhone.

My WhatsApp conversations contain information that I cannot afford to lose, that's why I cannot just drop this iPhone.

Recent versions of WhatsApp allow synchronizing conversation history via iCloud, but my version is too old and lacks this feature.

I was able to save photo and video files from WhatsApp conversations into iPhone, and then download them to PC via USB cable, but now I cannot do this because iPhone has zero free space, and I cannot free it (this is subject for another question).  Also, this approach does not work for text messages.

Situation becomes worse with each passing day, because as long as I cannot migrate WhatsApp to another smartphone, I keep receiving important information on this iPhone where it become trapped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the other post you mentioned that you are locked into using this iPhone 4. Since you wish to move WhatsApp from this device, will you be using another iPhone for running WhatsApp? As per [WhatsApp support document](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/20888066/#iphonebackup) you can backup and restore via iTunes.

Comment: No, I'm not migrating to another iPhone.  Also, are you sure this iTunes synchronization works with old WhatsApp versions?

Comment: I have never personally tested it, just quoting from the official document. It doesn't hurt to give it a try, if you have an extra iPhone handy.

Comment: What kind of research have you already done on this, including contacting WhatsApp support?

Comment: I found many instructions on the Internet, including ones on https://faq.whatsapp.com/, but all that I found was related to newer versions of WhatsApp.

Comment: See if individual chat can be exported. Swipe to left on a chat (or equivalent in your UI) and export it.

Comment: doesn't the WhatsApp offer any backup option ?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov backup the whole iPhone!

Comment: What does it mean to backup the whole iPhone?  How may I later extract individual files and messages from such backup?  WhatsApp offers iCloud synchronization solution, but not in versions as old as mine.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov See the answer, it is in continuation to my comment. What about the first comment, can individual chat be exported ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use iTunes to create a backup of your iPhone 4. The backup will contain the data files from WhatsApp. You can use a program such as iPhoneBackupViewer to view/export your WhatsApp messages:

http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/

Another more "down to earth" solution would be simply to use another camera phone to take pictures of each of the WhatsApp messages you would like to save.

Comment: Sounds promising, will try.  Thank you.

Comment: iBackup Viewer did it!  You are awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use an iPhone 4 as well (though, specifically the 4s), and stuck on iOS 9.

Except I'm able to manually backup my chat data through the app.
Just tried, and it worked, though you will need to test to see if you can restore the data to a new iPhone, since I don't have access to another one.

Here are the steps.

1. Go to settings
   [image: settings]

   2. Chats
      [image: chats]
2. Chat backup
   [image: chat backup]
3. Tap on "Back Up Now"
   [image: back up now]
4. That's it
   [image: done]

Comment: The iPhone 4S is not an iPhone 4, so you haven’t got an iPhone 4. As you mention, the 4S runs up to iOS 9 - but the iPhone 4 only runs iOS 7. This means that you have a completely different version of WhatsApp.

Comment: I did not realize that the regular iPhone 4 is stuck on iOS 7. I only remembered that the 4s has a better processor, but thought the differences stopped there. Thanks for the clarification.